# How to Implement native module in react-native?

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

I am following this guide
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#content

And also this website:
http://colinramsay.co.uk/2015/03/27/react-native-simple-native-module.html

But does not matter where i add the .h and .m files i always get the error:
Class ClassName was not exported Did you forget to use RTC_EXPORT_MODULE()?

Even if it the same code from the examples from react-native documentation, can anyone guide me where to add the .h and .m files and properly link them to the project?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a change in the native module API and it seems the docs haven't been updated accordingly. From the example in my article, SomeString.m should look like this:

```
//  SomeString.m
#import "SomeString.h"

@implementation SomeString

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(get:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{ 
  // Change this depending on what you want to retrieve:
  NSString* someString = @"something";

  callback(@[someString]);
}

@end
```

This ends up with the desired result and you can call it from JS in the same way as before. It looks like this only just happened:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/0686b0147c8c8084e4a226b7ea04585362eccea8

Comment: Awsome, it was just that, i changed that and everything started working. Instant fan now!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add a plain `RCT_EXPORT();` to any method you want to export. Works like a charm.

Comment: This approach is deprecated and has now been removed. It was slightly more convenient to use, but wasn't as good as the new system because we couldn't do proper type validation on the method arguments.