# App stops at LaunchScreen in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm playing around with React Native but the ios app does not start anymore. It just stops at the launch screen and I don't know how to debug properly. I don't even know what I did to break it that much.

When I run react-native log-ios the only thing that looks like an error to me is the following output, but I'm not sure if this is the cause of the error:

Class XXX was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE():

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTK9b.png)

Does anybody have an idea of what could get wrong or how I can debug a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

- close xcode

In Terminal:

- cd /path/to/Project
- npm install

Also check: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552377/how-to-implement-native-module-in-react-native/29557740#29557740).